# Create a histogram with different bins

Tags: python-3.x, histogram, bin

I want to create a histogram with my own data. I have like different bins ( 500-600 , 600- 700, 700-750,750-800,..). I have the absolute frequencies to that bins swell. I need to plot the relative freqs now in a histogram. I have 34 pieces in all bins ( in bin 500-600 is the absolute freq 2 , in bin 500 - 600 is the abs. freq 8,..)

For example, the relative freq of the bin 500-600 is 0.05.

How can i do that? With my code I have 0 in all the bins.

the variable relfreq is a list with all the relative frequencies in it. How can i connect now the relfreqs to the bins? I hope you get the idea of what i mean.

Greets Alex

```
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(relfreq, bins =[500,600,700,750,800,900,1200]  )
print(hist)
print (bin_edges)

plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist, width=1)
plt.xlim(min(bin_edges), max(bin_edges)) 
plt.show()
```